# How to integrate chat AI in the chat widget (Zoho SalesIQ)?

Tags: zoho, zoho-deluge

I have the URL to our custom chat AI.

On our website, we have a chat widget where the customer can select "Chat with AI Assistant".

When the customer clicks on "Chat with AI Assistant", we want to invoke the URL of our custom chat AI in the chat widget.

We are using Zoho SalesIQ.
I'm writing the Deluge script in SalesIQ as Plug.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e5S9S.png)

1. How can I achieve this?
2. How can I make a trigger to open the custom chat AI?

Thank you all in advance.

**Script 1 Try:**
res = invokeurl
[
url :"https://app.customgpt.ai/projects/18862/ask-me-anything?embed=1&shareable_slug=f5c159061c8"
type :GET
];
return res.toString();

**Script 2 Try:**
on chatWidgetTrigger:
{
if (trigger == "Chat with AI Assistant")
{
openURL("https://app.customgpt.ai/projects/18862/ask-me-anything?embed=1&shareable_slug=f5c159061c8");
}
}